# Only allowing Mongo user to access one collection

Tags: security, mongodb

I have an app that I want to tap into a centralized database but it only needs access to one of the collections, so I would like to restrict this Mongo user to accessing the documents for this specific collection, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, see [Collection-Level Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: Perfect, can you add that as an answer? I'll accept it, ty